# Tukey HSD, insignificant p-value when the confidence interval does not contain 0?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, multiple-comparisons, tukey-hsd-test

I am using TukeyHSD to do multiple comparisons. I am seeing strange results for some of the pairs: the adjusted p-value is greater than the specified significance level but the corresponding confidence interval does not contain zero!!

Here is the toy example:

```
 set.seed(1)

 K <- 8
 ns <- round(seq(10,100,length.out=K))
 resp <-tx <- NULL
 for (i in 1 : length(ns))
  {
   resp <- c(resp,rpois(ns[i],i*3))
   tx <- c(tx,rep(i,ns[i]))
  }
 tx <- factor(tx)
 amod <- aov(resp ~ tx)

 (what <- TukeyHSD(amod,"tx",conf.level=0.001))
```

The result is:

```
 Tukey multiple comparisons of means
 0.1% family-wise confidence level

 Fit: aov(formula = resp ~ tx)

       diff       lwr       upr     p adj
 2-1  2.700000  1.718027  3.681973 0.7386563
 3-1  5.533333  4.606644  6.460023 0.0113160
 4-1  8.985714  8.086145  9.885283 0.0000002
 5-1 11.421311 10.536867 12.305756 0.0000000
 6-1 14.037838 13.164403 14.911272 0.0000000
 7-1 17.493103 16.627472 18.358734 0.0000000
 8-1 20.540000 19.680189 21.399811 0.0000000
 3-2  2.833333  2.141315  3.525351 0.2386485
 4-2  6.285714  5.630459  6.940970 0.0000008
 5-2  8.721311  8.086978  9.355645 0.0000000
 6-2 11.337838 10.718949 11.956727 0.0000000 
 7-2 14.793103 14.185277 15.400930 0.0000000
 8-2 17.840000 17.240492 18.439508 0.0000000
 4-3  3.452381  2.883310  4.021452 0.0093115
 5-3  5.887978  5.343129  6.432827 0.0000000
 6-3  8.504505  7.977717  9.031292 0.0000000
 7-3 11.959770 11.446024 12.473516 0.0000000
 8-3 15.006667 14.502789 15.510544 0.0000000
 5-4  2.435597  1.938273  2.932922 0.0784209
 6-4  5.052124  4.574655  5.529593 0.0000000
 7-4  8.507389  8.044349  8.970429 0.0000000
 8-4 11.554286 11.102220 12.006352 0.0000000
 6-5  2.616526  2.168202  3.064851 0.0148083
 7-5  6.071792  5.638867  6.504717 0.0000000
 8-5  9.118689  8.697521  9.539856 0.0000000
 7-6  3.455266  3.045303  3.865228 0.0000274
 8-6  6.502162  6.104636  6.899688 0.0000000
 8-7  3.046897  2.666823  3.426970 0.0000862
```

The adjusted p-value of comparisons between 1 and 2 is 0.7386563 (insignificant difference between 1 and 2) but lwr = 1.718027 and upper = 3.681973, indicating that confidence interval does NOT contain zero? So should 1 and 2 be significantly different?! I see that this is happening in pairwise comparisons of 3-2 and 5-4. I appreciate any explanation why this is happening...

Comment: Maybe your use of `conf.level = 0.001` means that p-values under 0.999 are "significant".

Comment: I see! I somehow thought that conf.level specifiy the significance level. Thank you.

Comment: `TukeyHSD(amod,"tx")` returns the same `diff` and `p adj`, but the questionable confidence intervals include a $0$.  The `conf.level = 0.001` adjusts the `% family-wise confidence interval`, and in your case it changed it from the default of `95%` to `0.1%`.